# Undefined stdClass property

Tags: php

i am new to this and i am stuck with this error

> Undefined property: stdClass::$id in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\thesisApp\db\login.php on line 6

here is the code

```
<?php 
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "thesisAppdb");
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data->id);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data->username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data->password);

 $query = ("SELECT id FROM teacherdata WHERE username= '$username' and 
 password= '$password' and id = '$id'");
 $que = mysqli_query($con, $query);
 $count = mysqli_num_rows($que);

 if ($count == 1) {
 echo 'correct';

} else {
echo 'wrong';
}
?>
```

hope to hear news from anyone.

Comment: Your `$id` is still an object? can you print `$id` for debugging

Comment: Please, provide the output of `var_dump($data)`.

Comment: @mega6382 object(stdClass)#2 that is the output

Comment: OK, now can you provide and check the output of `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"))`

Comment: <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE) @mega6382 this what it outputed

Comment: @jayvee0917 You did put a `;` after the `var_dump()` right?

Comment: i missed it and then i added the **;** then this it what displayed after **object(stdClass)#2 (0) {
}
string(2) "{}** @mega6382

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the output of `var_dump`, that `file_get_contents("php://input")` contains an empty `json object`. Which when decoded provides an empty PHP `object`. So, you need to make sure that there is `id` key in the `json object` and on the PHP side you can use the following:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$id = 0;
if(isset($data->id))
{
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data->id);
}
```